# Do DWNominate scores take into account that not all votes are created equal?

Tags: united-states, congress, parties, measurement

Do DWNominate scores take into account that not all votes are created equal?

Two issues come to mind immediately:

- Some votes are so uncontroversial that almost nobody votes against (naming a Post Office?)
- Some votes are so extremely partisan that it's almost guaranteed that nealy 100% of the opposite party would vote against, while a reasonable chunk of your own party would ALSO vote against.
- More specifically, I am pretty sure that both the amount of such votes AND the extremeness of what's being voted on isn't necessarily distributed equally.

Does DWNominate address that (especially the last 2 points) somehow?

Answer (score 2):

DWNominate only takes into account formal [roll call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorded_vote) votes.  Wikipedia [explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOMINATE_%28scaling_method%29) the history:

> NOMINATE (an acronym for Nominal Three-Step Estimation) is a multidimensional scaling application developed by political scientists Keith T. Poole and Howard Rosenthal in the early 1980s to analyze preferential and choice data, **such as legislative roll-call voting behavior.** As computing capabilities grew, Poole and Rosenthal developed multiple iterations of their NOMINATE procedure: the original D-NOMINATE method, W-NOMINATE, and most recently DW-NOMINATE (for dynamic, weighted NOMINATE).

To address your specific points:

1. Things such as naming a post office are generally done by [voice vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_vote#United_States) or [unanimous consent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unanimous_consent), where the vote is effectively just accepted to be vastly in favor, and no actual vote is recorded.  They don't factor into DWNominate at all, because there is no record.
2. These votes are exactly what DWNominate is intended on tracking.  If there is a hard-line bill which even most of the people in your party will reject, and you vote against it, then you're more moderate then some of the people in your party.  It is worth noting that DWNominate does have two axes - the one everyone talks about (left/right) and a social axis.  More details are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOMINATE_%28scaling_method%29#Dimensions), but the relevant quote is: `The second dimension (vertical or y-axis) picks up attitudes on cross-cutting, salient issues of the day (which include or have included slavery, bimetallism, civil rights, regional, and social/lifestyle issues)`.
3. The previous two points mostly address this, but just to touch on the distribution: DWNominate scores are *not* set against an absolute definition of liberal vs. conservative, and those definitions change over time.  What it measures is how liberal vs. conservative each Congressman is *in relation to the rest of that Congressional session*.  So the more roll call votes, the more accurate the numbers will be.

Comment: I'm amazed that there's a TERM for this. "bimetallism". We should readapt it to modern political vernacular somehow

Comment: @DVK - Yeah, it is a fun word.  I'm not sure there's any use for a word that's so clearly based on "metal" in current politics, though.  And it's old enough that it'd fail as an appeal to a bygone era.  If you've got any ideas, I'd love to hear them...